# Java Heuristic Search

Tags: java, search, heuristics

I'm trying to write a heuristic search for a River problem. The problem is, I have X people with X weight and X can sail the raft, and they all have to get from 1 side of the river to the other.

I attempted to write the following; https://pastebin.com/h4adeVnv

```
    public int heuristic(State state){

    PersonState sState = (PersonState) state;

    if(sState.isBoatIsSouth()){

        return sState.isGoal() ? 0 : Collections.max(sState.listPersonsSouth).getWeight();
    }
    else {
        return sState.isGoal() ? 0 : Collections.min(sState.listPersonsNorth).getWeight();
    }

}
```

This gets me to 1 node off of the expected answer and cost-wise 1 move off.

I'm aware that the code doesn't really check the current state vs the goal state but I'm unsure how to write that.

Any suggestions on an alternative method or any adjustments I could make would be much appreciated!

Comment: in addition I tried to add the following

https://pastebin.com/E1VqNSKP

in attempt to make the search function more admissible by not overestimating the cost but same problem is still occurring

Comment: Can the raft sail only due to the weight? Or is there a space confinement?

Comment: my  bad didn't realize I forgot to say! there is a weight and space confinement  (can only fit a max of x  weight and y people)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried averaging the weight? Since the raft can only hold <= X amount of people, and also can only hold <= Y amount of weight, you could attempt to take the heaviest person(s) and group them with the lightest person(s) in an attempt to bring the average weight per person on the raft to optimal levels (optimal being the max weight the raft can hold / the max amount of people the raft can hold).

It could look something like this (writing pseudo code since I don't have your full code):

```
Raft raft = getRaft();
Double maxWeight = raft.getMaxWeight();
Double maxCapacity = raft.getMaxCapacity();
People[] people = getAllPeople();
Double optimalWeight = maxCapacity / maxWeight;
while(people > 0){
Person heaviestPerson = people.getHeaviestPerson();
Person lightestPerson = people.getLightestPerson();
Person secondLightestPerson = people.getSecondLightestPerson();

if((optimalWeight * 3 - (heaviestPerson.weight + lightestPerson.weight + secondLightestPerson.weight))
 < (optimalWeight * 2 - (heaviestPerson.weight + lightestPerson.weight))){
    raft.add(heaviestPerson);
    raft.add(lightestPerson);
    people.remove(heaviestPerson); 
    people.remove(lightestPerson);
}else{
    raft.add(heaviestPerson);
    raft.add(secondLightestPerson);
    raft.add(lightestPerson);
    people.remove(heaviestPerson); 
    people.remove(lightestPerson);
    people.remove(secondLightestPerson);
}
}
```

If you pair the heaviest and lightest people, you are removing the people with the highest variance from the optimal weight, and offsetting said variance to be more 'normal'. It becomes easier and easier to add people to the raft as you do this because as you remove each person with high variance, you are left with people that are closer to the optimal weight.

You could probably optimize it further using the methodology given too (possibly checking against the second heaviest person too, etc.)